# Custom Binding Adapter Best Practice

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding

I haven't seen an answer to this question -

I have a custom binding adapter for a RangeSlider View type. However, in it, I handle four attributes. Semantically, it makes sense, and I thought it would improve readability to group all four items together. My question being, is this bad practice? Are my assumptions incorrect?

Here is the code -

```
fun RangeSlider.setRangeSliderValues(sliderViewType: SliderViewType) {
    values = sliderViewType.initialSliderValues.map { it.toFloat() }
    valueFrom = sliderViewType.valueFrom.toFloat()
    valueTo = sliderViewType.valueTo.toFloat()
    stepSize = sliderViewType.stepSize
}
```

If it's helpful at all, here is the SliderViewType class

```
class SliderViewType(
    override val title: Criteria,
    val valueFrom: Int,
    val valueTo: Int,
    val initialSliderValues: List<Int>,
    val stepSize: Float
    ) : FilterViewType() {
    override val viewType = ViewType.SLIDER
...
```

Comment: it is very normal to group multiple attributes in a custom class to be used as a configuration parameters of a function or another class, i see nothing wrong with your implementation and i personally would do the same. only thing i would change is use a 
"Data Class" instead of a normal Class if the purpose of the class is to group multiple attributes with no other functionality

Comment: Bad practice versus doing what? How else might you choose to do it?